# How to get another player ID for Farmville 2 Country Escape?

Tags: facebook, farmville-country-escape, game-center

I chose to ask this question here because there doesn't seem to be any way to contact Zynga for this game. The button that's supposed to actually show me the contact options just redirects to a page that tells me what I should be seeing. I have no permissions on the forums despite the email saying that I do. I will appreciate any guidance on how to get official support.

My goal is for my friend and I to be able to play the game each using our own iPads and Facebook accounts. So this is what happened that led me to this problem:

1. My friend gets the game on his iPad using his Apple ID, plays the game with his Game Center ID but doesn't use Facebook Connect.
2. I get the game on my iPad using his Apple ID, play the game with my Game Center ID and use Facebook Connect.
3. Friend decides to use Facebook Connect, but I forgot I was logged in to my Facebook account on his iPad and he clicks the button in the game to connect.
4. His game connects to my Facebook so now it appears both our farms are tied to my Facebook and every time we try to play our own farms simultaneously the game will constantly ask us to pick between the device farm and the cloud farm.
5. We restart everything, uninstall, sign out of Facebook and Game Center, and sign in to our respective accounts and reinstall the game.
6. Now my friend is unable to connect his new farm to his Facebook because it keeps saying it's already connected to another, probably still mine.
7. It appears we have the same player ID when we check under the Options menu.

So is there any way for us to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find out how to send an email to Zynga. I clicked "Player Support" in the game which brought me to FAQ-like support page on their website. I selected "Tech/Loading" and at the very bottom I clicked "No, I need more help". That brought me to an email form.

There must be some kind of filtering system that determines whether you get to the email form or not because I just tried it as I was writing this answer and it just redirected me to the home page.

I described my exact problem in the email and within a couple hours I received a response from the support staff at `support@zynga.com`. After some back and forth emails he understood exactly what my problem was. I provided him with my player ID and he did some cleaning up from his end. I reinstalled the game and launched it **after** I had already logged into the proper accounts and I received a new player ID and everything worked.

Good to know I can get support. This happened over a Saturday and Sunday too.